# How to display MySQL data in rows based on a column category using PHP in Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, mysqli

In my 'magnums' table I have the following data:

[image: magnums table data]

What I want is to display the producer as a title and then the corresponding rows under that heading underneath that. **My desired output:** [image: desired output]

I'm very new to PHP and mysql so I'm not sure how to go about this but this is what I have so far:

**Model:**

```
class Magnum_model extends CI_Model {
        public function get_magnum_wines() {
          $query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM magnums');
          return $query->result();
        }
    }
```

**Controller:**

```
public function index() {
    $data['magnums']= $this->Magnum_model->get_magnum_wines();
    $this->load->view('magnums.php',$data);
    }
```

**View:**

```
<h3>Domaine Vincent Rapet</h3>
  <?php foreach($magnums as $magnum): ?>
      <div id="magnum-img">
          <div class="gallery">
              <img src="/BurgundyDirect/gallery/<?php echo $magnum->Image; ?>">
          </div><!-- gallery ends -->

          <div class="desc">
            <div id="wine-name">
              <h5><?php echo $magnum->Name_of_wine; ?></h5>
            </div>
            <h6><a href="#"><?php echo $magnum->Producer; ?></a><h6>
            <h4><?php echo $magnum->Magnum_price; ?></h4>
          </div>
      </div>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
```

**The output of the above code:** [image]

I don't know how to sort it to my desired output. Any help would be much appreciated and thank you in advance :)

Comment: `SELECT * FROM magnums ORDER BY Producer`

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I wish it was that easy too. Unfortunately, ORDER BY Producer only orders the  list alphabetically by the Producer. I'm looking to restructure the html somehow and extract the necessary data using php.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to show groups of products, you can get list of producers of producers and related products in controller.

1. In your producers model, create method, that get all producers (`select * from producers`).
2. Get producers in controller `$producers = $this->Producer_model->get_producers();`
3. Then create array with producer's name and products.

sample code:

```
$producerWithProducts = array();

foreach($producers as $producer) {
    $producerId = $producer->Id;
    $producerWithProducts[$producerId]['producerName'] = $producer->Name;
    $producerWithProducts[$producerId]['products'] =  $this->Magnum_model->get_magnum_wines_by_producer_id($producerId);
}
```

Then pass `$producerWithProducts` in template and iterate it.

Comment: Ok but how do I do this? :)

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: Where does the array with producer's name and products go? would this go in my magnums controller?

Comment: Could you elaborate on your foreach loop. I'm not quite getting it.

Comment: Also, what's in the model get_magnum_wines_by_producer_id?

Comment: In loop we iterate producers and create array with producer's name and products related to it. `get_magnum_wines_by_producer_id` is method that you should to create in Magnum_model to get products by producer's id.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same thing but with wine categories / colours so this is what I did:

First make a new table called producers with 2 columns: id and name.
In the wine table make a new column with the name producer_id.
The value of this column is corresponds with the id in the producers table.

Then you can iterate through it like this:

```
function extractWines() {

    $producers = mysqli_query("SELECT id FROM producers");

    foreach($producers as $key => $value) {
        $query = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM wines WHERE producer_id = " . $value . "");
        $rowname = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);

        $html = <<<HTML
        <h1>{$rowname['producer']}</h1>
HTML;
        echo $html;

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {

        $html = <<<HTML
        (html code of the item with styling)


HTML;
        echo $html;

        }  
    }
}
```

This should help you with your problem.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Do you know how to arrange this in the codeigniter framework?

Comment: I am not familiar with the codeigniter framework. So I don't know. What happens if you do my code in the framework?